# RNA seq .counts.txt to bigwig conversion

Tags: rna-seq, rna, bigwig

I've downloaded neuronal RNA seq data from GEO. The files are in .counts.txt format. Could I convert them to bigwig? If so, how?

Comment: Hi @Samir ... you've got the files from here https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/ cool, could you just fill in details about viewing and bigWig format for the rest of us?

Comment: Hi Michael. I want to load RNA seq data into HiGlass, a browser that I use to look at my HiC data. I have previously loaded RNA seq bigWig files into HiGlass. I just don't know if there is a way to load the text file format into HiGlass, so I wanted to know if I can convert the format to bigWig.

Comment: can you provide the GEO accession ? Sometimes they do provide bigwig but i suspect it's not very useful for RNAseq unless there's something specific u need

Comment: Hi, this is the GEO accession: GSE102838

Answer (score 1):

No, count-level data doesn't have the base-level resolution that is required in order to be usefully visualised on a genome browser. You need a BAM file (or raw FASTQ files that can be used to generate a BAM file) in order to do that.

"No" isn't completely correct: it'd be *possible* to take gene counts and information about gene annotation boundaries to shoehorn them into a BedGraph / BigWig file, but whatever comes out the other end of that isn't going to be a good representation of reality.